# How \topinsert differs from \pageinsert?

Tags: floats, plain-tex

In TeXbook p.116 it is said:

> ... suppose you make seven topinserts in a row, of
>   respective sizes 1, 2, 3, 9, 3, 2, 1 inches; the 9-inch one is actually a `\pageinsert`.

This wording is very curious. Why not to say "suppose you make three topinserts..., then pageinsert..., then three topinserts..."?

So, is `\topinsert` interchangeable with `\pageinsert` when height of the topinsert occupies the whole page?

While comparing these (see below), three questions arised.

The following file is used as a starting point:

```
\hrule height \vsize width300pt
\bye
```

Output is:

```
(p.tex [1] )
```

Now make a pageinsert:

```
\pageinsert
\hrule height \vsize width300pt
\endinsert
\bye
```

Output is:

```
(p.tex [1] [2] )
```

**Question 1:** Why second page is created?

Then make a topinsert:

```
\topinsert
\hrule height \vsize width300pt
\endinsert
\bye
```

Output is:

```
(p.tex [1]
Overfull \vbox (8.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active [2]
[3] )
```

**Question 2:** Why second and third pages are created?

**Question 3:**
Also, log file of the last example contains this:

```
\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x300.0, glue set - 1.0
.\glue(\splittopskip) 0.0
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
..\rule(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
.\penalty 10000
.\glue 12.0 plus 4.0 minus 4.0
```

Apparently, `\bigskipamount` glue is used in the end of `\topinsert`.
But if we do `\showthe\skip\topins`, `0.0pt` is output. Why?

**UPDATE** I checked that if in the last example we do `\bigskipamount=0pt`, then output becomes identical to example with `\pageinsert`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

topinsert and pageinsert mostly share the same code, with one boolean switch distinguishing them

```
  \def\topinsert{\@midfalse\p@gefalse\@ins}
  \def\midinsert{\@midtrue\@ins}
  \def\pageinsert{\@midfalse\p@getrue\@ins}
```

So for example the bigskip that you ask about appears at the end of topinserts as `\ifp@ge` is false in that case and `\endinsert` has

```
   \ifp@ge \dimen@\dp\z@
    \vbox to\vsize{\unvbox\z@\kern-\dimen@}% depth is zero
    \else
     \box\z@\nobreak\bigskip
                     %%%%%%
     \fi
```

This is also explained in TeXbook p.115:

> Plain TEX automatically adds a “bigskip” below each topinsert; this will
>   separate the caption from the text.

...

> ... if you say ‘\pageinsert  \endinsert’, the
>   vertical mode material will be justified to the size of a full page (without a
>   bigskip below it) ...

Comment: Is `\ifp@ge` the cause of difference between full-page `\topinsert` vs `\pageinsert`? What is `\ifp@ge` for? Also (see "Question 1"), why two pages are created? (What does the output obtained by `\tracingpages=1` mean?)

Comment: And what does this `\bigskip` mean, after all?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko `\bigskip` is just `\vskip\bigskipamount` and it is only added if `\ifp@age` is false which is just if `\topinsert` rather than `\pageinsert` is used, as I show,

Comment: `\p@gefalse` is done also if `\midinsert` is used. I still do not completely understand what `\ifp@ge` is for. And why do we need this `\bigskip`?

Comment: yes I was just comparing top and page insert (as that's all you asked about) I do not understand your comment about what `\ifp@ge` is for, it is just used in the places I show to distinguish top and page inserts. You don't _need_ bigskip just that the plain tex design chose to put a big skip between top inserts and the main page body that is not needed for page inserts as they take the whole page.